# how to fix it: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6 in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    var arrTwoD : Array<IntArray> = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(1,1,1,0,0,0),
            intArrayOf(0,1,0,0,0,0),
            intArrayOf(1,1,1,0,0,0),
            intArrayOf(0,0,2,4,4,0),
            intArrayOf(0,0,0,2,0,0),
            intArrayOf(0,0,1,2,4,0)
    )

    var max = Int.MIN_VALUE
    for (x in 1..4){
        for(y in 1..4){
          var currentSum = arrTwoD[x][y] + arrTwoD[x][y+1] + arrTwoD[x][y+2] + arrTwoD[x+1][y+1] + arrTwoD[x+2][y] + arrTwoD[x+2][y+1] + arrTwoD[x+2][y+2]
            max = kotlin.math.max(max, currentSum)
        }
    }
    println(max)
}
```

output:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6`

Comment: you are doing arr[6][5], arr[6][6] etc. at the `arrTwoD[x+2][y] + arrTwoD[x+2][y+1] + arrTwoD[x+2][y+2]` when having only 6 elements. As indexing is zero based so it should be `x in 0..3`

Comment: @echoHan Don't forget to mark the answer as "Accepted" if it solved the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Indexing in arrays starts with 0, so when you're trying to access element with index 6, it's actually 7-th element in the array (which doesn't exist in arrays you're provided). Hence you're getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Just change your loops to go from 0 to 3 and you should be fine:

```
for (x in 0..3){
        for(y in 0..3){
```